# Spatialite table column is function in itself

Tags: qgis, spatialite, qspatialite

GOAL: I'm trying to filter all the 1's in a spatial boolean operation in Qspatialite, the spatialite plugin for QGIS.

ATTEMPTED SOLUTION: My solution is to perform the boolean query first, export the resulting table AS a table second, then query THAT table for all the 1's, third.

PROB W/ SOLUTION: Problem is, column to be filtered has a header that is in itself a function (i.e., "within(geom 1, geom 2)"). Thus, the header cannot be called in the command dialog as a simple string, because it inevitably becomes a command/function.

This is what I ran:

`SELECT Towns.name, Schools.name, within(Schools.geom, Towns.geom) from Towns, Schools`

So, `within(Schools.geom,Towns.geom)` becomes the table header, which I need to filter for 1s.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just use an alias, and subsequently reference the alias (in the example below, InTowns)?

```
SELECT Towns.name, Schools.name within(Schools.geom, Towns.geom) AS InTowns from Towns, Schools
```

As an alternative, you could do:

```
SELECT Towns.name, Schools.name FROM Towns, Schools WHERE Within(Schools.geom, Towns.geom)
```

In the latter case there would be no filtering to do, as by default you would only have records where the schools are within the towns.

Comment: I already went straight ahead with your second suggestion. Worked perfectly!